# Git Bash で ssh-keygen コマンドのマニュアルを表示するには？

Tags: openssh, git-bash

**Q1.ssh-keygenコマンドのヘルプを表示するためには？**
下記の通り`ssh-keygen --help`を試したら、unknown option と表示されました
省略されている(と思われる)箇所(...)もあります

```
$ ssh-keygen --help
ssh-keygen: unknown option -- -
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa] [-m format]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-m format]
                   [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -l [-v] [-E fingerprint_hash] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -B [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -D pkcs11
       ssh-keygen -F hostname [-f known_hosts_file] [-l]
       ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
       ssh-keygen -G output_file [-v] [-b bits] [-M memory] [-S start_point]
       ssh-keygen -T output_file -f input_file [-v] [-a rounds] [-J num_lines]
                  [-j start_line] [-K checkpt] [-W generator]
       ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I certificate_identity [-h] [-U]
                  [-D pkcs11_provider] [-n principals] [-O option]
                  [-V validity_interval] [-z serial_number] file ...
```

---

**Q2.ssh-keygenコマンドをキャンセルするためには？**
下記を試したら、処理が進んでしまいました
これをキャンセル(このプロセスをkill？)するためには？

```
$ ssh-keygen -help
Enter file in which the key is (/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

---

**Q3. Git Bash で man コマンドが使用できない理由は？**
そういう仕様だから？？
man コマンドに相当するものはありますか？

```
$ man ssh-keygen
bash: man: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Q1. ssh-keygen コマンドのヘルプを表示するためには？

Git Bash にインストールされているバージョンに限らず、ssh-keygen にはヘルプを表示するオプションが存在しないので、コマンドにヘルプを表示させる確実な方法は存在しないはずです。

#### Q2. ssh-keygen コマンドをキャンセルするためには？

通常の Bash と同じく、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> で SIGINT を送れます。

#### Q3. Git Bash で man コマンドが使用できない理由は？

man コマンドがインストールされていないからです。man ファイルもインストールされていないので、Git Bash のデフォルト設定のままマニュアルを参照することはできません。

Answer (score 3):

解決済みですが、補足も兼ねて。

> ssh-keygenコマンドのヘルプを表示するためには？

[ソースコード](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/1dfadb9b57c2985c95838a0292d1c2f6a501896e/ssh-keygen.c#L2689-L2691)を見る限り、`-?`オプションもしくは不正なオプションでヘルプが表示されます。（どのみちunknown optionと言われますが…。）
ともあれ、コマンドライン引数だけではわからないでしょうから、素直に公式のオンラインヘルプを参照するべきです。[ssh-keygen](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen)

> 下記を試したら、unknown option と表示されました
>
> ```
> $ ssh-keygen --help
> ssh-keygen: unknown option -- -
> ```

マイナスを二つ重ねる形式のオプションはGNU形式です。対して`ssh`はOpenBSDが開発したものですので、`--help`を試す方が間違っています。

> 省略されている(と思われる)箇所(...)もあります
>
> ```
> ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I certificate_identity [-h] [-U]
>            [-D pkcs11_provider] [-n principals] [-O option]
>            [-V validity_interval] [-z serial_number] file ...
> ```

省略ではなく複数の`file`を指定できる意味です。

> Git Bash で man コマンドが使用できない理由は？

[#696 Could you include manpages for the included programs?](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/696#issuecomment-196515495) によるとGit for Windowsは一般の利用者向けであり、開発者向けとなる`man`は含めない方針だそうです。